# Draw concentric arcs

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you help to draw concentric arcs as in the figure below?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\x in{-2,-1.5,-1,-.5} 
\draw(\x,-1)--(\x,1);
\draw(0,.2) rectangle (.3,1.5);
\draw(0,-1.5) rectangle (.3,-.2);
\draw(0.15,-.1)--(0.15,.1);
 \draw[red] (2,-1.5) arc (-30:30:3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this pictures is that the slit has the same width in each of them... this is misleading concerning diffraction -- the picture D is contradicting picture C, in my point of view...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the `expanding waves` decoration, which comes with `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[slit/.pic={%
\draw[thick,fill=gray] (-0.15,1.5) |- (0.15,0.2) -- (0.15,1.5)
(-0.15,-1.5) |- (0.15,-0.2) -- (0.15,-1.5);
\draw (0,0.15) -- (0,-0.15);
\node[anchor=south,font=\sffamily\bfseries] at (0,1.6){#1};},
decoration={expanding waves,angle=33}]
  \pic (0,0) {slit=A};
  \foreach\X in {-2,-1.5,-1,-.5} 
  {\draw(\X,-1)--(\X,1);}
  \draw[thick,-latex] (-3,0) -- (-2.2,0);
  \foreach\X in {0.5,1,1.5,2} 
  {\draw(\X,-0.2)--(\X,0.2);}
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
  \pic (0,0) {slit=B};
  \foreach\X in {-2,-1.5,-1,-.5} 
  {\draw(\X,-1)--(\X,1);}
  \draw[thick,-latex] (-3,0) -- (-2.2,0);
  \foreach\X in {0.5,1,1.5,2} 
  {\draw (\X,-0.5-0.25*\X) arc(-90:0:0.2)-- (\X+0.2,0.5+0.25*\X-0.2) 
  arc(0:90:0.2);}
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
  \pic (0,0) {slit=C};
  \foreach\X in {-2,-1.5,-1,-.5} 
  {\draw(\X,-1)--(\X,1);}
  \draw[thick,-latex] (-3,0) -- (-2.2,0);
  \draw[decorate] (0.25,0) -- (2,0);
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm,xshift=6cm]
  \pic (0,0) {slit=D};
  \foreach\X in {-2,-1.5,-1,-.5} 
  {\draw(\X,-1)--(\X,1);}
  \draw[thick,-latex] (-3,0) -- (-2.2,0);
  \draw[decorate] (2,0) -- (0.25,0);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is picture D physically correct? C shows the diffraction of planar waves  in the  slit (which is correct), but why should there be 'inverted' circular waves after the slit, when planar waves from the left -- I have never seen this before...

Comment: I don't speak on behalf of the OP, but, my guess would be this diagram is part of a multiple choice question. So some of the answers are deliberately 'wrong'?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer None of the four is physically correct, and the question is about concentric arcs, not about physics.

Comment: @marmot -- they are not all totally incorrect as long as Huygens principle is correct ;-) But the slits in all pictures have the same width, slightly narrower than the wave length, so it is pretty near to diffraction condition ...

Comment: The title with `concentric arcs` is confusing anyway....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Then you can also justify D, and I did not choose the title. D can be justified by claiming that this is not an ordinary slit, but these are two bars which can move/oscillated in the x direction only. If the wave hits them from the right, you indeed get something of the sort shown here.

Comment: @marmot: If the wave in D approaches from the right, I agree with you (I thought about already), but the arrow from left to right at the planar waves contradicts this as well....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This arrow only says "look here" ;-)

Comment: @marmot: Netter Versuch, aber: "Nein" :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hmm, are you suggesting that I should replace my answer by `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}~\end{document}` because the previous graphs are unphysical? ;-)

Comment: @marmot: Too much text... just say `\bye` ;-)