# Drawing Concentric Arcs

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw some concentric arcs. I thought it would be as simple as decreasing the radii of the arc by the same amount I decrement the coordinate, but it does not look right. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\tikzset{decorate sep/.style 2 args=
{decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=#1,shape sep=#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[decorate sep={1mm}{1.2mm},fill,red] (0,0) arc (70:110:1);
\draw[decorate sep={1mm}{1.2mm},fill,red] (0,-.2) arc (70:110:.8);
\draw[decorate sep={1mm}{1.2mm},fill,red] (0,-.4) arc (70:110:.6);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of desired result?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473429/draw-concentric-arcs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use polar coordinates for the start points to make sure that these are concentric arcs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\tikzset{decorate sep/.style 2 args=
{decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=#1,shape sep=#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[decorate sep={1mm}{1.2mm},fill,red] (70:1) arc (70:110:1);
\draw[decorate sep={1mm}{1.2mm},fill,red] (70:0.8) arc (70:110:.8);
\draw[decorate sep={1mm}{1.2mm},fill,red] (70:0.6) arc (70:110:.6);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!!!